# Correct way to define order in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP 2 (version 2.10.5) query that joins 2 tables, let's say I query on Model1 and join Model2 and Model3. I want to order my data by Model2.field_1 and Model3.field_2.

When I use this way:

```
'order' => ['Model2.field_1', 'Model3.field_2']
```

Or this way:

```
'order' => ['Model2.field_1' => 'ASC', 'Model3.field_2' => 'ASC']
```

Only the Model2.field_1 is added to the order part of the query.

When I use this way:

```
'order' => 'Model2.field_1, Model3.field_2'
```

Both fields are added to the order part of the query, they are quoted and everything so CakePHP interprets them correctly.

Why is this? And what is the correct way?

Comment: Can you add your query, and associations between models. that would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two examples should be the correct way of using `order` in CakePHP 2. You'll find examples of using `order` in the official docs under [Retrieving Your Data](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

So you should be either using:-

```
'order' => ['Model2.field_1', 'Model3.field_2']
```

Or:-

```
'order' => ['Model2.field_1' => 'ASC', 'Model3.field_2' => 'ASC']
```

Both would be interpreted the same. The [documentation for Models](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#order) explicitly describes the available formats for `order`.

I suspect that if these are not working in your query then there is another issue not shown here. I believe that when Cake is generating the query it will ignore order statements that aren't relevant to the query. For example, if you are trying to order on  a has-many `contain` or you are using pagination and trying to order of a column that hasn't been configured correctly (see docs of [pagination ordering](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)).